# equivalent of mvn build-classpath in ant

Tags: java, maven, ant, classpath

I am beginner in Maven and Ant projects.I have a trouble with some Ant tasks.I don't know how to build class-path of dependencies in Ant; while it can be done in maven projects by:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath
```

How can i do above task in Ant?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it using classpath tag in your build.xml you can refer example below

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source ">
     <!--  Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build}  -->
     <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}/classes" includeantruntime="false">
         <classpath>
             <fileset dir="${hadoop.home}/">
                 <include name="**/*.jar"/>
             </fileset>
             <fileset dir="${hadoop.home}">
                 <include name="hadoop-common-*.jar"/>
             </fileset>
         </classpath>
     </javac>
 </target>
```

Comment: Thank you.But how can i make the full path of  these classpath directories from my build.xml and put them in a txt file?

Comment: @AliFara you can provide absolute path, for fileset dir I have used a variable to substitute it, instead you can  provide your full path.

Comment: Thank you for your help. i have another question;supose we have a build.xml file that contains these dependecies classpath , is there any task or command in ant to get these classpahtes from my build.xml file?

Comment: @AliFara If your aim is to build the jar just run ant build, or if you want read the xml file use some xml parser in Java such as saxparser and get the value of class path tag from build.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Ant is more like an imperative programming language. You don't have the amount of meta-information in your `build.xml` as you have in a `pom.xml`. The easiest thing would be to add some code to your ant "compile" target that writes the classpath to a file when you do a compile.

You can also externalise the classpath in a separate `libraries.xml` file (that was done in our company when we used Ant) which allows you to edit and read the data more easily. You could even write another ant target for that.